# eps images won't show up

Tags: subfloats, eps, epstopdf

I have a figure where each image shows a frame of a video, so their order is important. I have the eps files in the same folder, and I get no errors, but when I run it the images are not shown, instead there are table cells and the name of the file is written in the box. How can I resolve this?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S001}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S002}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S003}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S004}} \\
\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S005}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S006}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S007}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S008} \\
\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S009}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S010}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S011}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S012} \\
\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S013}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S014}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S015}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S016} \\
\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S017}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S018}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S019}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S020}
\caption{ A temporal sequence}
 \label{fig:temp}
\end{figure}
```

More details:

```
% This is samplepaper.tex, a sample chapter demonstrating the
% LLNCS macro package for Springer Computer Science proceedings;
% Version 2.20 of 2017/10/04
%
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
%
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{caption}
% Used for displaying a sample figure. If possible, figure files should
% be included in EPS format.
%
% If you use the hyperref package, please uncomment the following line
% to display URLs in blue roman font according to Springer's eBook style:
% \renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
%
\title{Contribution Title\thanks{Supported by organization x.}}
%
%\titlerunning{Abbreviated paper title}
% If the paper title is too long for the running head, you can set
% an abbreviated paper title here
%
\author{First Author\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-1111-2222-3333} \and
Second Author\inst{2,3}\orcidID{1111-2222-3333-4444} }
%
\authorrunning{F. Author et al.}
% First names are abbreviated in the running head.
% If there are more than two authors, 'et al.' is used.
%
\institute{Institute}
%
\maketitle              % typeset the header of the contribution
%
\begin{abstract}
The abstract should briefly summarize the contents of the paper in
150--250 words.

\keywords{First keyword  \and Second keyword \and Another keyword.}
\end{abstract}
%
%
%
\section{First Section}

--Where my figure is--

% ---- Bibliography ----

% \bibliographystyle{splncs04}
% \bibliography{mybibliography}
%
\begin{thebibliography}{8}


\bibitem{ref_url1}
LNCS Homepage, \url{http://www.springer.com/lncs}. Last accessed 4
Oct 2017
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sound like you are in "draft" mode

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with modes, can you explain?

Comment: Editors can be set to not show graphics so as to speed up viewing but you have not explained what you are using as an editor or what settings you have in your preamble hence we expect an MWE to see what you are doing

Comment: I use TeXworks, not sure where to find that setting

Comment: not a setting in the editor, what you describe sounds as if you have `\documentclass[draft]{....}` but as you have not shown any relevant code nor the log file, hard to know.

Comment: Okay, I will try to add them, but it is majorly a template, not sure if sharing all would be too much on here. And I don't have a draft mode by looking at \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

Comment: Ok I t should work replace that first {S001} with the word {example} and does it show ?

Comment: No, it gives an error, says can't find image:

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `example' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.66 ...{S003}\includegraphics[width = 1in]{S004}}
                                                   \\
?

Comment: It converts the eps to pdf by the way, I mean in the folder they are generated

Comment: Sorry that should have been {example-image-a}

Comment: Yes, I see an image with letter A

Comment: Ok the eps loading is correct thus the images or filenames are suspect

Comment: They are named like this: S001.eps S002.eps etc. Now, I don't remember how I got the eps images in the first place (I got this from an older latex file and forgot about it, originally they were jpeg)

Comment: @dusa jpeg would be better (as they can be simply included by pdftex) eps files can not, pdftex has to call ghostscript to convert them to pdf.

Comment: the guidelines say we should use eps though, I am just not sure if I got the eps through latex(is it possible?) or if I just used gimp etc. I think the ghost script is working as I do have eps to pdf converted files generated after I run the latex file. But they just won't show up for some reason.

Comment: If the eps were converted as you hinted to S001-eps-converted-to.pdf then they should load if you  comment out third line e.g. %\usepackage{epstopdf}

Comment: Then I get this error, the file is there but it is formatted as:S001-eps-converted-to.pdf while it asks for fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf, also interesting it says "draft setting" 
  ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using d
raft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.146 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.eps}

Comment: Again apologies that is a default file and I do have a fig1-eps in the folder so it worked for me

Comment: no problem, thanks a lot for your help, but why do I get file format as "fig1" when I have the file names written as S001 etc

Comment: all I did was to remove the package \usepackage{epstopdf} so not sure how it relates to filenames

Comment: I have copied that file to S002.eps and it is now showing when I comment out again fig1 is a **test file included with your template** and converts perfectly to pdf without any settings (but I do have a known good version of ghostscript in my system path)

Comment: Ok, I see, but it says " using draft setting. " so perhaps that is where it failslike you suggested initially but if it is not in documentclass then how?

Comment: without diving ito the llncs class file I cant say but it looks like it modifies some default behaviours and without reading all the docs do not know if they want images to be supplied as fig1 fig2 fig3 etc hence a default fig 1 test file

Comment: okkk, so there was an example image below the document which I didn't check (I left guidelines to refer to whenever I needed) and it had the name fig1 - \begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.eps}
\caption{A figure caption is always placed below the illustration.
Please note that short captions are centered, while long ones are
justified by the macro package automatically.} \label{fig1}
\end{figure} So when I removed it completely, it worked! Thanks!!

Comment: I note it also works best if \usepackage{epstopdf} is loaded as last not first

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the problem continues as I wanted to another image, now it won't even generate pfds. So annoying. I get this error (and again draft mode message) ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `S-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

Comment: sorry did not see that comment since to "ping" me you need to use @KJO the suggestion to comment out EPStoPDF was for those you had already converted but it is likely needed  (with -shell-escape and a ghostscript on path) to do the conversion first time round your basic issue is it seems there is a conflict in packages somewhere that is alternately with/without epstopdf commented letting it build not show OR show not build !!